# How to parametrize dependencies versions in gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Say I have a set of dependencies in a gradle build:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.7.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.7.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.7.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web :4.3.7.RELEASE"
    ...
}
```

Say a new release `5.0.0.RELEASE` comes out. I don't want to have to edit each dependencies in my `build.gradle`.

Is there a way I could set a variable in this file which I could use for all dependencies? In other words, I would only modify the value of this variable instead of modifying all dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. try:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext.ver = "4.3.7.RELEASE"

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$ver"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$ver"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$ver"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$ver"
}
```